# How to track the person who share the link in React or Flutter

Tags: reactjs, flutter, share, sharing

Is there a package for React Js or Flutter that I can use to know that an authenticated user has shared a link. When I use **react-share** or **flutter's share package** it does not show if the link was shared or not.

Comment: How would those packages know? They can neither know where it was shared to, nor can they know whether the recipient actually clicked it. *You* can find out if your user *created* a sharable link and *you* can find out if it was clicked.

Comment: For example, if I share the link to my email, to open it at my desktop PC later today, did I "share" the link? Technically, I absolutely did. But it's probably not what you want to track.